# AWT: swap button objects

Tags: java, object, button, awt

Is it possible to swap 2 button references in java awt?

If 2 buttons are swapped, their name should be updated in the frame automatically. But even calling button.repaint () after making the swap does not make any visible change.

Changing a buttons name with button.setLabel (" ") is not a sufficient solution.

Events of a button get caught by a ActionListener. See cast from actionEvent to Button object..

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test extends Frame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Button> buttonsToSwap = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        initButtons();
        addButtons();
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initButtons() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buttons.add(new Button(Integer.toString(i + 1)));
        }
    }

    private void addButtons() {
        for (Button b : buttons) {
            add(b);
            b.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
        }
    }

    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            buttonsToSwap.add((Button) e.getSource());
            if (buttonsToSwap.size() >= 2) {
                buttonSwap(buttonsToSwap.get(0), buttonsToSwap.get(1));
                buttonsToSwap.clear();
            }
        }

        private void buttonSwap(Button b1, Button b2) {
            Button temp = b1;
            b1 = b2;
            b2 = temp;
            // button.repaint()???
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show us your current implementation?

Also, what are you looking to do by "swapping the buttons"? Are you looking to change what the Listener does? Because you can make two Listeners in the Class, then assign them to the different buttons when needed.

Comment: purpose: i just want to swap 2 button object, similar to a eight puzzle but easier..

Comment: @FrancisBartkowiak no, I dont need 2 separate listeners, 1 Listener should be enough to do what I want to do.. just swapping 2 Objects and display the result on my Frame